# node_modules has a lot of files I don't know

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I'm going through a tutorial by Kent C. Dodds on building an open source library. So far I have used npm to install chai, commitizen, cz-conventional-changelog, mocha, and unique-random-array.

I'm not sure when but I just noticed that my node_modules file became very large. There are around 100 folders just in the root of the node_modules folder.

I have attached two screenshots of some of the node_modules.

I do remember running npm install sementaic-release-cli without the global flag for a split second before realizing my mistake and quickly exiting the command. Could that split second have installed all these modules? If this is a result of my mistake then is there any way I can fix it?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version of `npm` are you using? [As of version 3](https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#flat-flat-flat), `npm` installs all dependencies as flatly as possible. So even though you only installed a few modules, those modules have dependencies of their own, and npm installs them all next to each other whenever possible.

Comment: I'm currently using 2.14.7

I thought the dependencies of packages I install are within their own node_modules folder?

Comment: @Ephapox: npm _used_ to install the dependencies in a hierarchy, but now if there are no version clashes between modules, npm will install them as flatly as possible to reduce module duplication (i.e. two packages that rely on the same third package).

Comment: Oh wait I think you're right. I'm using nvm and when I was working on this I was using 'nvm use stable' which installs node v5 and npm v3.

I hope this isn't too far off from the topic but will running npm install <package> and then canceling it cause a partial install of packages in my node_modules or will it simply cancel the entire installation?

Comment: npm will clean up after itself. If you install a package and then cancel it before it finishes, npm will remove any dependencies it installed _if_ they weren't already there.

Answer (score 0):

Commitizen author here. Previously we had a bunch of our dev dependencies as regular dependencies. The latest Commitizen version removes this. If you clean out your node modules, install the latest Commitizen version, then rerun npm install you should have fewer dependencies.